# SSL certificate issued by and valid dates show in Chrome but not FF

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, https

When I connect to my site over HTTPS, chrome displays the padlock and when you click it it shows the issuer and dates.

However when you view the site (over HTTPS) in firefox, it says: This website does not supply indentity information, Your connection to this site is only partially encrypted...etc

The certs were issued by RapidSSL.

Thanks,

Dave

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that FireFox has a current list of root certificates and that you have properly installed any chained certificates as well?

Comment: RapidSSL is in the list of certificates as a: Software Security Device - is this correct? And yes pretty sure the chained certificate file is installed. Is this the SSLCACertificateFile in apache - aka intermediate certificates? Dave.

Comment: It should be enabled for Server Authentication & Client Authentication.  If it isn't you may want to talk with RapidSSL to get it cleared up.